# Does AirBitz have federated servers?

Tags: data-security, safety, airbitz

I have been looking for a service that uses federated servers.

Why?

Because I am paranoid. And because companies pay me to be imaginative in my foe analogies.

Comment: // , It may seem too simple, but it's important. Even a well supported y/n would suffice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We don't have federated servers right now but we do utilize open source, publicly accessible libbitcoin nodes which both Airbitz and 3rd parties host. This is a fully compatible replacement to bitcoind nodes but provides much faster blockchain queries, similar to Electrum servers. If you'd like to run one, we'll include it in the list of servers that our clients could access.

Our Git encrypted storage "sync" servers are also peer-to-peer but currently only we host them.

Comment: // , Part of the reason I ask is because it's not always clear what needs to happen when a Bitcoin wallet provider's infrastructure just _dies_. Any company that uses a Blockchain API for something, should fold in multiple providers for that something. GreenAddress's multisig makes this especially problematic, but they offer nLockTime transactions for each deposit.